# When Scrolling Up/ Down from Top of Page My Back to Top Button does not Disappear/ Reappear

Tags: html, css, button, servicenow

I am trying to create a back to top button that only appears when I scroll down. Mine is just stuck top the bottom right of my screen. I am on ServiceNow creating a Knowledge Base article. It contains HTML, and CSS.
The button's scroll to top feature works. It just stays on screen though. How can I make it so it only appears when the user scrolls down? None of the other answers in similar questions on here did not work for me.

here is my code:

```css
/*Floating Back-To-Top Button*/

#myBtn {
  --offset: 100px;
  margin-top: calc(100vh + var(--offset));
  text-decoration: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 10px;
  float: right;
  right: 18.5%;
  left: 77.25%;
  max-width: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: sans-serif border-color: rgba(85, 85, 85, 0.2);
  background: #000;
  padding: 1px;
  border-radius: 100px;
}


/*On Hover Color Change*/

#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #7dbbf1;
}
```

```html
<a href="#top" style="color: white;" id="myBtn">Back to Top &uarr;</a>

<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ullamcorper malesuada proin libero nunc consequat. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis ut diam. Lectus urna duis convallis
  convallis tellus id. Rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis. Laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar.
  Dignissim cras tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at. Cras semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. At risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque. Nunc mattis enim ut tellus elementum. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est. Tempus
  urna et pharetra pharetra massa. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum. Nec feugiat in fermentum posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Et netus et malesuada fames ac. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar. Mauris sit amet
  massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel. Bibendum enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. Feugiat vivamus at augue eget arcu dictum varius duis. In hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum.
  Quam id leo in vitae turpis massa. A iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo. Sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat. Dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed. Justo laoreet sit amet cursus sit. Senectus et
  netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Vitae sapien pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et. Pretium fusce id velit ut tortor. Gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim convallis
  aenean. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed. Gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus. Convallis convallis
  tellus id interdum. Sapien faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed. Ultrices in iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra. Sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque. Eget gravida cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis. Tincidunt vitae semper quis lectus
  nulla at volutpat. Sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in. Imperdiet massa tincidunt nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper. In ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Lacus vestibulum sed arcu non odio euismod lacinia. Aliquam
  sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et egestas quis ipsum suspendisse. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum. Est ullamcorper
  eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim diam quis. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada. Suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus mattis. Nulla aliquet porttitor lacus luctus accumsan tortor posuere ac ut. Aliquet sagittis
  id consectetur purus ut. Et odio pellentesque diam volutpat commodo sed egestas egestas. Vulputate ut pharetra sit amet aliquam id. Sollicitudin ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. Eu tincidunt tortor aliquam nulla facilisi. Est ullamcorper
  eget nulla facilisi etiam dignissim. Cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget nulla. Vitae proin sagittis nisl rhoncus mattis rhoncus urna neque viverra. Velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat nam
  at. Sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis. Id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Ultricies leo integer
  malesuada nunc vel risus commodo viverra maecenas. Iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet. Proin fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet. Blandit aliquam etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non. Placerat
  orci nulla pellentesque dignissim enim. Facilisi morbi tempus iaculis urna id. Nunc pulvinar sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin. Aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Nec ullamcorper sit
  amet risus nullam eget felis eget nunc.</p>
```

Tried my code above, and its not working as expected.

Answer (score 1):

1. Determine the point in your document which, when it scrolls in or out of the top of the viewport, is the point at which you want your “back to top” button to appear or disappear. For example, let’s say this point is at the end of the second paragraph.
2. Create a scroll tracking element at this point, which is a single pixel high and invisible. I prefer to remove it from the document flow with `position: absolute`, but this is optional.
3. Create an [intersection observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Intersection_Observer_API) which checks the `y` value of the `boundingClientRect` of the element it receives. If this value is less than zero (the element is above the viewport), show your button, otherwise (the element is in or below the viewport) hide your button.
4. Finally, tell your intersection observer to observe your scroll tracking element.

Here is a snippet to demonstrate. Note that I have left the scroll tracking element visible so that you can see it; look for a thin white line on the right side just below the second paragraph. Typically you would hide this element with `visibility: hidden`.

```js
document.getElementById('back-to-top').addEventListener('click', evt => {
  window.scrollTo(0, 0)
})

const observer = new IntersectionObserver(entries => {
  if (entries[0].boundingClientRect.y < 0) {
    document.getElementById('back-to-top').classList.add('visible')
  }
  else {
    document.getElementById('back-to-top').classList.remove('visible')
  }
})

observer.observe(document.getElementById('scroll-tracking'))
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  background: black;
  color: #888;
  margin: 1em;
}

p:has(#scroll-tracking) {
  position: relative;
}

#scroll-tracking {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 1px;
  width: 10px;
  background: white;
}

#back-to-top {
  background: lime;
  padding: 1em;
  border: 5px solid white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 2em;
  right: 2em;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.3s;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: bold;
  cursor: pointer;
}

#back-to-top.visible {
  opacity: 1;
}

#back-to-top:hover {
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<button id="back-to-top">Back to top</button>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas tempor nunc mauris, sit amet placerat tortor lobortis dapibus. Nam lectus eros, maximus ac magna vel, congue consequat eros. Fusce id pretium diam. Cras sit amet pharetra ante. Sed quis commodo quam, vel facilisis ipsum. Vestibulum sodales iaculis arcu, et fringilla nisi ullamcorper sed. Donec interdum sit amet est non accumsan. Donec non augue feugiat, fermentum nunc non, convallis est. Cras vel ligula nec odio faucibus ultricies. Sed vulputate tortor eget pretium convallis. Cras interdum elit eget mi porta suscipit. Morbi ut velit diam. Etiam finibus eros et efficitur rutrum. Quisque viverra metus ac eleifend imperdiet. Quisque pretium ut purus vitae tempus. Duis varius risus congue velit faucibus, sed interdum purus consectetur.
</p>
<p>
Cras volutpat velit non mi sagittis condimentum. Cras tempor aliquet turpis sed pretium. Nunc aliquet sodales turpis quis ultrices. Duis auctor accumsan enim, quis maximus ex malesuada a. Donec a felis ut erat tempus euismod non vel neque. Proin lectus massa, sagittis at imperdiet nec, consequat ut neque. Sed vel placerat neque, vel varius urna. Vivamus interdum euismod urna a accumsan. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus.
<span id="scroll-tracking"> </span>
</p>
<p>
Nulla rhoncus aliquam mauris, eu pretium dolor auctor in. Maecenas a sollicitudin dolor, eget commodo quam. Proin et dui sed ligula vulputate egestas. Quisque eget augue vitae purus placerat pharetra. Aliquam rhoncus convallis lorem, sed facilisis odio blandit scelerisque. Vivamus viverra urna ac nulla interdum, eget ullamcorper leo maximus. Mauris nec feugiat enim. Nam congue, dui sit amet vestibulum posuere, leo mauris fermentum lorem, eget bibendum velit nunc quis leo.
</p>
<p>
Curabitur eget ullamcorper justo, sit amet dictum neque. Fusce vitae ligula et felis auctor vulputate vel suscipit nibh. Integer a felis varius purus vestibulum viverra. Morbi venenatis placerat augue sit amet commodo. Sed dapibus molestie eros, vitae ultrices nunc commodo aliquam. Vivamus tempus mollis massa vel egestas. Donec ut ante quis eros commodo volutpat. Proin sem nisi, viverra ac sem tristique, consectetur laoreet sapien. Vivamus suscipit orci vel euismod scelerisque. Nullam sed pulvinar tellus. Nullam pulvinar arcu eget nibh rutrum, eget faucibus ligula ullamcorper.
</p>
<p>
Sed sed cursus leo. Nam molestie eleifend leo, nec fermentum risus maximus ac. Pellentesque eget placerat ipsum. Vestibulum tempor quam justo. Fusce dapibus turpis non ante faucibus suscipit. Fusce rhoncus eleifend ipsum et lacinia. Curabitur nec congue arcu. Mauris dignissim magna ligula. Nullam ultrices, metus sit amet ultrices porttitor, turpis ligula interdum enim, eu pellentesque purus quam ut arcu. Nullam aliquet vitae tortor vel tincidunt. Fusce maximus lacus diam, sed elementum ligula condimentum vel. Sed consequat orci ac nunc gravida, at accumsan magna porttitor.
</p>
<p>
Mauris vulputate quam ac purus laoreet, nec ultrices eros placerat. Fusce id nisi ex. Nunc ornare tellus nisl, suscipit fermentum quam sodales sit amet. Ut ex magna, tempor nec ex sed, ornare ornare sem. Proin gravida turpis urna, vitae posuere purus consequat sit amet. Donec laoreet tempor massa. Praesent porta mauris vitae neque condimentum, non volutpat felis eleifend.
</p>
<p>
Aliquam aliquam a est eget cursus. Ut eu tempus justo, rutrum dapibus ex. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Nulla ornare nisi sit amet arcu semper maximus. Praesent eu augue eget mi sodales sodales. Praesent sodales neque malesuada, euismod est in, lobortis turpis. Nam blandit facilisis mauris. Ut ac ex rhoncus, ornare velit ac, aliquam nibh. Quisque euismod mauris quis nisl consectetur vulputate. Pellentesque mattis, tellus ut dictum dictum, urna ligula sodales magna, euismod malesuada ipsum quam nec elit.
</p>
<p>
Duis sit amet eros non est lacinia posuere et et ex. Proin in dui ornare ex eleifend pharetra. Etiam eros urna, euismod eget porttitor et, tempor quis turpis. Nullam sollicitudin suscipit lorem, maximus pellentesque turpis dictum sed. Integer fringilla gravida tellus sit amet facilisis. Pellentesque vel porta justo. Proin vehicula eget tortor ut condimentum. Phasellus interdum urna a condimentum dapibus. Sed commodo elit a metus vestibulum, ac vehicula mi tincidunt. Duis ante quam, posuere eget purus et, mollis congue tortor. Orci varius natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nunc quis orci porttitor, dictum libero sit amet, feugiat ipsum.
</p>
<p>
Nunc auctor lorem vitae neque sodales cursus. Sed scelerisque tempor tincidunt. Praesent eu pretium mi. Duis vitae venenatis nunc. Integer dolor sapien, vehicula ac dui id, fermentum malesuada justo. Donec ullamcorper enim sed nulla egestas condimentum. Etiam vitae dapibus sem, ut efficitur nulla. Donec laoreet, nunc quis aliquet blandit, erat nibh facilisis nibh, ut fermentum nisl dolor vel dui. Nunc pulvinar scelerisque urna, ut dictum purus placerat ac.
</p>
<p>
Nam mattis ipsum at metus placerat maximus. Sed sed enim nunc. Aenean dapibus, lorem non congue volutpat, tortor orci egestas leo, eu efficitur erat orci sit amet libero. Praesent quis convallis metus. Cras eget ligula nec tortor mollis vestibulum et facilisis tellus. Aliquam erat volutpat. Sed malesuada, lectus vulputate tristique mattis, lacus nisl tempus sem, in aliquet dolor neque sed nisl. Nulla facilisi. Nulla a pharetra felis, eu aliquet urna. Phasellus mattis mauris eget mauris laoreet, et accumsan magna laoreet. Maecenas a condimentum diam. Integer et neque odio.
</p>
<p>
Etiam feugiat tempus nibh, quis mattis enim porttitor eu. Praesent congue gravida nisi, sit amet convallis lectus sagittis et. Praesent rutrum ante nec lectus congue, congue pharetra sem efficitur. Vivamus eros mauris, pellentesque in aliquam at, vehicula consequat neque. Sed in pharetra lorem. Vivamus porttitor lectus risus. Vestibulum malesuada vestibulum ullamcorper. Nulla lacus purus, faucibus sit amet urna ac, placerat congue lectus. Ut iaculis risus eu pretium cursus. Quisque ac pharetra orci, ut convallis libero. Praesent auctor commodo quam sit amet aliquam. Integer tortor neque, cursus sit amet maximus sit amet, ultrices sed arcu. Nulla volutpat libero non ipsum auctor consectetur. Cras non malesuada felis, vel maximus ligula. Curabitur euismod porta semper. Ut posuere eget libero ac consequat.
</p>
<p>
Mauris tristique, leo sit amet aliquam varius, urna elit scelerisque nisi, non iaculis lectus augue id sapien. Phasellus euismod tellus in sodales finibus. Suspendisse potenti. Aenean malesuada sapien quis eleifend volutpat. Cras quam arcu, iaculis vel ornare vulputate, feugiat quis enim. Nullam auctor, libero vestibulum imperdiet tincidunt, justo tellus varius justo, a finibus magna purus eu est. Nam interdum odio in ligula ultricies, quis pulvinar lectus pulvinar. Fusce quis sem tincidunt, mattis massa eu, bibendum enim. Vivamus arcu arcu, aliquam eget suscipit id, tempor sed nibh. Nullam mi mauris, facilisis vitae massa a, facilisis vulputate velit. Phasellus facilisis egestas erat id elementum.
</p>
<p>
Proin non libero tortor. Nam scelerisque vel odio interdum pretium. Sed non metus magna. Praesent ullamcorper venenatis risus, quis semper purus. Donec vitae lectus id magna dignissim laoreet at ac urna. Aenean sapien dolor, egestas vitae nisl quis, ornare ullamcorper nibh. Nulla facilisi. Fusce maximus dapibus scelerisque. Donec sagittis leo mi, eget aliquet odio sodales rhoncus.
</p>
<p>
Nunc sollicitudin risus feugiat lacinia luctus. Vivamus iaculis ultrices blandit. Sed lobortis varius dapibus. Fusce vel justo eu est elementum ultricies eget vel dolor. Donec faucibus ex eget leo interdum, maximus accumsan orci pellentesque. Suspendisse interdum dolor lectus, et venenatis massa posuere eu. Etiam cursus lorem vitae tortor consectetur vestibulum.
</p>
<p>
Maecenas id lectus at velit euismod venenatis a ac dolor. Nullam quis volutpat ante, eu congue quam. Aliquam a gravida massa. Ut hendrerit in odio sed fermentum. Aliquam erat volutpat. Donec sed odio interdum, aliquam augue a, vulputate lorem. Nulla sed mattis odio. Sed volutpat tincidunt mauris sit amet porta. Etiam non nisi odio.
</p>
```